Continuous numbering of single figures and figure with subfigures
Similar to the question "Continuous subfigure numbering", but slightly different: I have an article with multiple figures, some of which have subfigures.
Firstly, I would like every image (i.e. every figure without subfigures and every subfigure) to be numbered continuously, preferably without having to add subfigures to every figure as in the aforementioned question. I could probably figure out how to use the same counter for the figure and subfigure environment, but that would lead to gaps in the numbering, as a figure with subfigures would increment the counter twice.
Secondly, if possible I would like the caption of figures that do have subfigures to contain the full range of subfigure numbers, i.g. "Figure 2–3: ...".
For example, this
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{fig1.jpg}
    \caption{Foo}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{fig2.jpg}
        \caption{Bar}
        \label{fig:fig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{fig3.jpg}
        \caption{Baz}
        \label{fig:fig3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Bar & Baz}
\end{figure}

should turn into this:

Figure 1: Foo













Figure 2: Bar
Figure 3: Baz


Figures 2–3: Bar & Baz




Is that possible? How can I eliminate the gaps in numbering from simply merging the counters?

Just read the author's instructions properly and I don't think I need this anymore, but I'll keep the question up just in case.

Manual creation of this for an article seems sufficient... how many of these do you have that makes it require specialized handling (for convenience, I assume)?

You could replace every subfigure with a minipage.  They have the same arguments.  A subfigure us basically a minipage with a different caption.

@Werner I have 49 images and might want to add some more, I already started using subfigures but it turns out the journal requires continuous numbering.

I was able to use the following, borrowing from answers to Continuous subfigure numbering and Print subfigure range in caption. This also makes the figure caption like "Figures 1--4" when applicable.
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\gdef\MySubcaptionFirst{}\gdef\MySubcaptionLast{}}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subcaptions}{\MySubcaptionRange{#1}{#2}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=subcaptions}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{subfigure}{
    \ifx\MySubcaptionFirst\@empty
        \addtocounter{figure}{1}%
        \xdef\MySubcaptionFirst{\csname thesubfigure\endcsname}%
        \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
    \else
        \refstepcounter{figure}%
        \xdef\MySubcaptionLast{\csname thesubfigure\endcsname}%
    \fi
}
\newcommand*\MySubcaptionRange[2]{%
    \ifx\MySubcaptionFirst\@empty
        #1 #2%
    \else
        \ifx\MySubcaptionLast\@empty
            #1 \MySubcaptionFirst%
        \else
            #1s \MySubcaptionFirst--\MySubcaptionLast
        \fi
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{}
\makeatother

